# Building Eclipse IDE from scratch - how to specify the target OS?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, build

This post is about building the whole Eclipse IDE from the source code - and more in particular how to specify the target OS you want to build the executable for.

[image]

I found the following tutorial to guide me through the build procedure: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlatformDevelopment/article.html

Especially chapter 13 of that Tutorial is helpful. I will describe the steps that need to be taken one by one here - so you don't need to read the vogella tutorial.

**NEEDED SOFTWARE :**

Apparently you need to have the following software installed on your (Windows) machine:

- Git
- Maven Version 3.3.1 (make sure that the bin folder where you extract Maven is added to the PATH. For installation instructions see https://maven.apache.org/install.html)
- Oracle 1.8 JDK or higher (don't forget to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable)

Now you're ready to start:

**STEP 1 :**

Create a new folder in the `C:\` disk. Let's name it `C:\myEclipse`. This will be the folder in which we pull the Git repository of the latest Eclipse version.

**STEP 2 :**

Open the Windows `cmd` shell with administrator privileges (right click on `cmd` icon if you made one on your desktop, and select `open with admin rights`). Go to that folder through the command `cd C:\myEclipse`. Now type the following command: `git config --system core.longpaths true`. This notifies Git that long names can occur in the repository. Forget this command and it will result in errors later on.

**STEP 3 :**

Clone the Git repository:

```
git clone -b master --recursive git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git
```

Now you should have some patience for all the sourcecode to get copied to your local folder.

**STEP 4 :**

Finally it is time to start the build. The build procedure will already take hours, so it is wise to skip the unit tests. Therefore do not forget to add the `-DskipTests` parameter. This is the command to start the build:

```
mvn clean verify -DskipTests
```

After some hours, the build should be finished.

**STEP 5 :**

The results of the build should now be in the following folder:

`C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.releng.tychoeclipsebuilder\sdk\target\products`

Notice that the Eclipse IDE is built for all possible target machines. 32-bit Windows, 64-bit Windows, Macintosh, Linux, ... No wonder it takes hours! I would like to build for just one single target - for example my 64-bit Windows machine. This will hopefully reduce the build time significantly and allow me to verify code changes quicker.

Does anyone know how to achieve this?

---

**EDIT :**

I have added the argument `-Dnative=win32.win32.x86_64` to the build command. Unfortunately, I get an error after 15 to 20 mins. This time, I've added the argument `-X` as well, to get debug information:

```
                      ...

[INFO] equinox-sdk ........................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] org.eclipse.rcp.id ................................. SKIPPED
[INFO] org.eclipse.rcp.sdk.id ............................. SKIPPED
[INFO] org.eclipse.platform.ide ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] org.eclipse.platform.sdk ........................... SKIPPED
[INFO] org.eclipse.sdk.ide ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] eclipse-junit-tests ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] eclipse.platform.repository ........................ SKIPPED
[INFO] platform-aggregator ................................ SKIPPED
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 23:54 min
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-06-19T18:12:14+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 668M/3263M
[INFO] -----------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8: run (natives) on project org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64: An Ant BuildException has occured: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.swt\bundles\org.eclipse.swt\buildSWT.xml:915: The following error occurred while executing this line:
[ERROR] C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.swt\bundles\org.eclipse.swt\buildSWT.xml:1012: exec returned: 1
[ERROR] around Ant part ...<ant antfile="build.xml" target="build_libraries"/>... @ 4:54 in C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.swt.binaries\bundles\org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64\target\antrun\build-main.xml
[ERROR] -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-antrun-plugin:1.8:
    run (natives) on project org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64:
        An Ant BuildException has occured:
            The following error occurred while executing this line:
            C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.swt\bundles\org.eclipse.swt\buildSWT.xml:915: The following error occurred while executing this line:
            C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.swt\bundles\org.eclipse.swt\buildSWT.xml:1012: exec returned: 1 around Ant part ...<ant antfile="build.xml" target="build_libraries"/>... @ 4:54 in C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.swt.binaries\bundles\org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64\target\antrun\build-main.xml
                at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:212)
                at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153) 
                at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145) 
                at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
                at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
                at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
                at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
                at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
                at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
                at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
                at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:863)
                at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:288)
                at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:199)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
                at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
                at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
                at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
    Caused by:
        org.apache.maven.plugin.MojoExecutionException:
            An Ant BuildException has occured:

                The following error occurred while executing this line:
                C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.swt\bundles\org.eclipse.swt\buildSWT.xml:915:

                The following error occurred while executing this line:
                C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.swt\bundles\org.eclipse.swt\buildSWT.xml:1012: exec returned: 1 around Ant part ...<ant antfile="build.xml" target="build_libraries"/>... @ 4:54 in C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.swt.binaries\bundles\org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64\target\antrun\build-main.xml
                    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:342)
                    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(Default BuildPluginManager.java:134)
                    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:207)
                    ... 20 more
                Caused by: C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.swt.binaries\bundles\org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64\target\antrun\build-main.xml

                :4: The following error occurred while executing this line:
                C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.swt\bundles\org.eclipse.swt\buildSWT.xml

                :915:The following error occurred while executing this line:
                C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.swt\bundles\org.eclipse.swt\buildSWT.xml:1012: exec returned: 1
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:568)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:443)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
                    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor67.invoke(Unknown Source)
                    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTarget(Project.java:1364)
                    at org.apache.maven.plugin.antrun.AntRunMojo.execute(AntRunMojo.java:313)
                    ... 22 more
                Caused by: C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.swt\bundles\org.eclipse.swt\buildSWT.xml

                :915: The following error occurred while executing this line:
                C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.swt\bundles\org.eclipse.swt\buildSWT.xml:1012: exec returned: 1
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.ProjectHelper.addLocationToBuildException(ProjectHelper.java:568)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:443)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.CallTarget.execute(CallTarget.java:105)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
                    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor67.invoke(Unknown Source)
                    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
                    ... 33 more

                Caused by: C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.swt\bundles\org.eclipse.swt\buildSWT.xml:1012: exec returned: 1
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExecute(ExecTask.java:643)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.runExec(ExecTask.java:669)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.ExecTask.execute(ExecTask.java:495)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:292)
                    at sun.reflect.GeneratedMethodAccessor67.invoke(Unknown Source)
                    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.dispatch.DispatchUtils.execute(DispatchUtils.java:106)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.Task.perform(Task.java:348)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.execute(Target.java:435)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.Target.performTasks(Target.java:456)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeSortedTargets(Project.java:1393)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.helper.SingleCheckExecutor.executeTargets(SingleCheckExecutor.java:38)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.Project.executeTargets(Project.java:1248)
                    at org.apache.tools.ant.taskdefs.Ant.execute(Ant.java:441)
                    ... 46 more
[ERROR]
[ERROR]
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException
[ERROR]
[ERROR] After correcting the problems, you can resume the build with the command

[ERROR]   mvn <goals> -rf :org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64
```

---

I still have no answer, so I started a bounty. Please reproduce **step 1** until **step 5** on your machine (with the `-Dnative=win32.win32.x86_64` argument added to the fourth step). Do you achieve a successful build of the Eclipse IDE for just one OS target (preferably Windows 64-bit)? Does the build go faster - compared to the general build process that targets all OS's?

PS: I've got some other questions related to the Eclipse "Build from scratch" topic. If you're interested:

- [Building Eclipse IDE from scratch - how to choose CDT over JDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929070/building-eclipse-ide-from-scratch-how-to-choose-cdt-over-jdt)
- [Building Eclipse IDE from scratch - how to specify the target OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37885323/building-eclipse-ide-from-scratch-how-to-specify-the-target-os)
- [Building Eclipse IDE from scratch - making bigger icons sometimes successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929996/building-eclipse-ide-from-scratch-making-bigger-icons-sometimes-successful)

Let us all unite to build the Eclipse IDE ourselves - and tweak it to our needs ;-)

---

**EDIT :**

Mr/Mss. Zapl wrote an interesting comment. He/She thinks that the `-Dnative` argument is not correct, after he/she read the following link:
http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ide.eclipse.cbi.devel/896

Hopefully we'll get closer to the answer now :-)

---

**FINAL EDIT :**

Suddenly this question catched the attention of the community. I got a lot of suggestions/answers in a short time. I cannot verify every single one of them right now because the build procedure takes about 2 hours.

I have 19 hours left to award the 50 points bounty. Please let me know if you successfully reproduced the STEPS 1..5 from this question on your own machine, and succeeded to *build the Eclipse IDE from scratch for one specific OS*. I will award you the bonus :-)

Comment: `exec returned: 1` means that the ant build process invoked from the maven build process tried to execute some program but it returned an errorcode. The actual error message that this program probably printed should appear earlier in the log, and may need some additional -debugverboseidontknowtherightcommand option to become visible. Or try executing the command from buildSWT.xml:1012 manually in a console.

Comment: How do I do this: "Try executing the command from buildSWT.xml:1012 manually in a console"? I'm too much of a newbie to the maven build procedure :-)

Comment: I meant executing the command from the [exec task](https://ant.apache.org/faq.html#batch-shell-execute) in the windows `cmd` window (the command that this step tries to execute seems to be something like `cmd /c '${build_dir}/${build_file}' ${swt.arch} ${xulrunner_target} install ${clean}` but you'd have to figure out what all those $placeholders resolve to). However, I think after reading http://comments.gmane.org/gmane.comp.ide.eclipse.cbi.devel/896 that `-Dnative` is the wrong option as it seems to build more things than the standard build.

Comment: Thank you Mr./Mss. Zapl. I've added your interesting comment as an **EDIT** to my question. Hopefully this brings us one step closer to the solution.

Comment: From the exception stack trace, it looks like build failed because `Maven` failed to clean the output directory which was in use by some process. Could you please manually delete all target directories and re-run your build command as suggested by Compass once again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This snippet is taken from a working pom.xml that exports to win32.win32.x86_64.
Maybe some parts are not required for your project but it may be a good starting point to add this to your pom file.

```
..
..
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.20.0</version>
            <extensions>true</extensions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
            <version>0.20.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <resolver>p2</resolver>
                <environments>
                    <environment>
                        <os>win32</os>
                        <ws>win32</ws>
                        <arch>x86_64</arch>
                    </environment>
                </environments>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
            <artifactId>tycho-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>0.20.0</version>
            <configuration>
                <compilerArgument>-err:-forbidden</compilerArgument>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
..
..
```

**EDIT**

As mentioned in the comments I followed your steps and had some problems. I solved most of them now. If someone else also gets a lot of errors here are some solutions.

- In the file eclipse.pde.ui/pom.xml line 19: the version was 4.6.0-SNAPSHOT, but has to be 4.7.0-SNAPSHOT
- Hint: To speed up the build you can add e.g. "-T 4" to the mvn command to enable parallel builds. I finally ended with >mvn clean verify -DSkipTests -T 4 -Dnative=win32.win32.x86_64

After this fix I was able to run until I got the same errors mentioned in the initial question.
I went to the project folder \eclipse.platform.swt.binaries\bundles\org.eclipse.swt.win32.win32.x86_64 and started an Ant build (Apache Ant version 1.9.7) and it finished without errors. But I got the same errors when it was executed by the Maven build.
Thus, I checked lines 915 and 1012 of the file \eclipse.platform.swt\bundles\org.eclipse.swt\buildSWT.xml. After setting failonerror="false" (is set to "true" by default) in both lines I was able to continue with the build.  *I assess this as a very poor solution and it should not be the final solution for a problem to disable such tests.*

Finally, I ended with errors in project org.eclipse.pde.build.tests and stopped following the problems.
The whole project seems to be misconfigured in many parts and I could not find a better solution so far. People should remember the golden rule not to commit anything that breaks the build to avoid such problems. Maybe the problems will be solved after a few updates to the repo.

Comment: Thank you Stefan,
How exactly should this snippet be inserted in the `.pom`? And where do I find the correct `.pom` file in which I need to insert this snippet?
It would be great if you try it out on your system. Do you have experience in building Eclipse from scratch?

Comment: Sorry, I do not know your project structure (and do not have a few hours right now to test it; maybe during the weekend). This snippet is part of a pom.xml project used for an eclipse plugin that is exported using a .product file. This pom is on the top level of the project and a parent-pom for all lower level poms. Thus, you should try to add it to the highest level pom to check if it does anything at all for you.

Comment: My 'project structure' is the result from going through all steps 1 .. 5. I did not change anything to the code (yet).

Comment: Hi @StefanDolezel , I just inform you that I made a final edit to my question. :-)

Comment: Hi @StefanDolezel, I just awarded the bounty to you on the last minute. Hopefully you'll try the test out on your pc this weekend ;-)

Comment: @K.Mulier Thanks for the bounty. Even though, I do not know if I deserve it, yet. I tried to reproduce this problem yesterday in the evening but got a lot of different errors during step 4. As I could not fix these errors in a reasonable time I could not build anything at all. But I did some further research. Following this [link](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform-releng/Platform_Build) there is a section called "Building natives". There you can see that it should be sufficient to use e.g. "mvn clean verify -DskipTests=true -Dnative=gtk.linux.x86_64" as suggested by other users in this thread.

Comment: Another thing I found is the eclipse-platform-parent\pom.xml file. Here several settings are saved. In line 32 you can see , e.g., that you should use a Maven version >= 3.3.3 (<prerequisites><maven>3.3.3</maven></prerequisites>). Around line 301 you can find the <environments> tag. Here all environments are listed. Following my first idea you could try to uncomment all environments you do not need.

Answer (score 2):

There are multiple projects that are built here

1. SWT natives. (-Dnative=)
2. IDE. (platform independent)

SWT natives are built(by SWT team) every day at 19:00 EST/EDT everyday and pushed to eclipse.platform.swt.binaries.git repo. This build requires a quite a bit of dependencies like visual studio, xulrunner, WebKit, etc. For trying out a build I don't suggest you to attempt this .

CBI(Common Build Infrastructure) does the eclipse plugin builds and signing and packaging. This process is platform independent.

CBI build starts at 20:00 EST/EDT daily and the swt.binaries are picked up only during packaging. The packaging would probably takes about 5 minutes in the whole process. So I am not expecting much difference if you specify only 1 target to build.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. I upvoted it, because I see some potential in what you said. But I still struggle to completely understand it. Can you give some clarifications? For example, what does this mean: "the IDE build picks up the natives for packaging"?
I'm a newbie to the Eclipse build procedure - and probably some readers of this post as well. Please try to explain it as if you are talking to a newbie ;-)

Comment: Ide package is created by cbi(common build infrastructure). This cbi picks up Swt natives from the Swt.binaries repo and get the added to the IDE package as a plugin fragment

Comment: Hi @SravanKumarLakkimsetti , I just inform you that I made a final edit to my question. :-)

Answer (score 2):

To targeting just one single OS you have to specify the target environment in the parent *pom.xml* file (see [Tycho - Target runtime environment](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Reference_Card#Target_runtime_environment)):

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.eclipse.tycho</groupId>
    <artifactId>target-platform-configuration</artifactId>
    <version>${tycho-version}</version>
    <configuration>
        <environments>
            <environment>
                <os>win32</os>
                <ws>win32</ws>
                <arch>x86</arch>
            </environment>
        <environments>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

If you use PDE Build instead of Maven/Tycho the Ant property is `configs`, e.g, `-Dconfigs="win32, win32, x86"`.

FYI: [Eclipse Platform CI which generates the Eclipse SDK archives](https://hudson.eclipse.org/platform)

Comment: Thank you so much. I will try it out tomorrow morning.

Comment: Hi @howlger , I just inform you that I made a final edit to my question. :-)

Comment: Hi @howlger . I think you are closest to the solution. If you give me your word that you'll try out this solution on your machine (and inform us about the results), then I'll reward the bounty to you right now. I only have 30 mins left to award the bounty to someone.

Comment: Hi @k-mulier. I used PDE Build a couple of times, not Maven/Tycho. So feel free to give the bounty someone else.

Answer (score 1):

From https://wiki.eclipse.org/Platform-releng/Platform_Build#Building_natives

> Optionally, you can pass -Dnative= parameter with one of the following options to compile the natives for the specified native.

- cocoa.macosx.x86
- cocoa.macosx.x86_64
- gtk.linux.x86
- gtk.linux.x86_64
- win32.win32.x86
- **win32.win32.x86_64**
- win32.wce_ppc.arm

The arg would be `-Dnative=win32.win32.x86_64`

Comment: Thanks a lot! I am trying it out right now. It seems like it's building just fine. I will let you know if the build finishes without errors :-)

Comment: Do you know how to tell the `maven` builder that you've got multiple CPU cores to do the job?

Comment: Unfortunately the `-Dnative=win32.win32.x86_64` argument leads to some strange error.

Comment: I've made an **EDIT** on my question :-)

Comment: I'm pretty horrible at interpreting Ant Build errors. You should probably run it with verbose error logging and as a separate question entirely if it still doesn't make sense.

Comment: Thank you so much. I can do that after the weekend, when I've got access again to that computer. I'll let you know the result.

Comment: Hi @Compass , I've just redone the build process, this time with the `-X` argument to display the debug information.

Comment: @K.Mulier I can't make heads or tails of that one. What you can probably do is create a new question about it, along with the specified lines from the buildswt.xml file.

Comment: What is the buildswt.xml file?

Comment: Hi @Compass. Could you try it on your pc? Just to see if it is something related to my machine or not. Thank you so much :-)

Comment: The buildswt.xml file is an ANT file listed in the error log. I wouldn't be able to build it since I don't know what version you're running, and I'd have to set up a lot of IDE/Maven stuff since I typically don't code from my home computer.

Comment: You can win a bounty now if you setup the build environment ;-)

Comment: Hi @Compass , I just inform you that I made a final edit to my question. :-)