# Building Eclipse IDE from scratch - how to choose CDT over JDT?

Tags: java, eclipse, git, maven, build

Lately I decided to build the Eclipse IDE from scratch - so I have the freedom to tweak it to my needs. The very first action I'm taking is enlarging the icons. Even the newest Eclipse Neon edition has still somewhat small icons on a 4k display.

[image]

I found the following tutorial to guide me through the procedure of building Eclipse from scratch: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipsePlatformDevelopment/article.html

Especially chapter 13 of that Tutorial is helpful. I will describe the steps that need to be taken one by one here - so you don't need to read the vogella tutorial.

**NEEDED SOFTWARE :**

Apparently you need to have the following software installed on your (Windows) machine:

- Git
- Maven Version 3.3.1 (make sure that the bin folder where you extract Maven is added to the PATH. For installation instructions see https://maven.apache.org/install.html)
- Oracle 1.8 JDK or higher (don't forget to set the JAVA_HOME environment variable)

Now you're ready to start:

**STEP 1 :**

Create a new folder in the `C:\` disk. Let's name it `C:\myEclipse`. This will be the folder in which we pull the Git repository of the latest Eclipse version.

**STEP 2 :**

Open the Windows `cmd` shell with administrator privileges (right click on `cmd` icon if you made one on your desktop, and select `open with admin rights`). Go to that folder through the command `cd C:\myEclipse`. Now type the following command: `git config --system core.longpaths true`. This notifies Git that long names can occur in the repository. Forget this command and it will result in errors later on.

**STEP 3 :**

Clone the Git repository:

```
git clone -b master --recursive git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git
```

Apparently this git repository contains the Eclipse IDE with JDT installed. I'm not a Java developer, so I'd like other options.
After lots of searching, I finally found the webpage where the choices of git repositories is listed: https://git.eclipse.org/r/#/admin/projects/?filter=platform The choices are endless:

- git clone git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform
- git clone git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.common
- git clone git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.debug
- git clone git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.images
- git clone git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.news
- git clone git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.releng
- ...

Which one should I choose to build the barebones Eclipse platform? And which one for building the Eclipse platform with CDT installed?

**STEP 4 :**

Finally it is time to start the build. The build procedure will already take hours, so it is wise to skip the unit tests. Therefore do not forget to add the `-DskipTests` parameter. This is the command to start the build:

```
mvn clean verify -DskipTests
```

After some hours, the build should be finished.

**STEP 5 :**

The results of the build should now be in the following folder:

`C:\myEclipse\eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator\eclipse.platform.releng.tychoeclipsebuilder\sdk\target\products`

**THE QUESTIONS :**

1. When you run the resulting `eclipse.exe` file, you'll notice that you're dealing with the Eclipse for Java Developers. That is - to my understanding - the basic Eclipse platform plus the JDT (Java Development Tools) plugin. I am not a Java Developer, and would like to build the basic Eclipse platform with the CDT plugin (C Development Tools) for pure C programming. How do I do that?
2. Notice that the Eclipse IDE is built for all possible target machines. 32-bit Windows, 64-bit Windows, Macintosh, Linux, ... No wonder it takes hours! I would like to build for just one single target - for example my 64-bit Windows machine. This will hopefully reduce the build time significantly and allow me to verify code changes quicker. I've already posted this question here: [Building Eclipse IDE from scratch - how to specify the target OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37885323/building-eclipse-ide-from-scratch-how-to-specify-the-target-os)
   Unfortunately, the given answers to that question did not lead to a correct result.
3. The third issue I'm trying to fix is the icon size. Eclipse has painfully small icons. For those who are interested in making them bigger, please refer to this StackOverflow question: [Building Eclipse IDE from scratch - making bigger icons sometimes successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929996/building-eclipse-ide-from-scratch-making-bigger-icons-sometimes-successful)

Thank you so much for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your CDT issue, I would try getting the [pure UI first](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/eclipse.platform.ui/developer) then add in the [CDT](https://projects.eclipse.org/projects/tools.cdt/developer)

As for your Maven issue, look at the maven code and see if there are options for how to build. I can't really help too much without being able to see the maven file.

Comment: Where can I find "the maven file"? I'm a maven-newbie :-)

Comment: You mention "I would try getting the pure UI first, then add in the CDT". That is a very good idea. I agree full 100%. But what is the git repository address for that? Clearly it is not what I thought : `git clone -b master --recursive git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.releng.aggregator.git`. Maybe you know the correct address? Thank you so much for your help :-)

Comment: maven file is usally `pom.xml` and the urls `git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.runtime` and `git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt`

Comment: So am I correct if I do the following actions:
(1) Clone the git repository `git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/platform/eclipse.platform.runtime` and build that source code to get the clean UI.

(2) Clone the git repository `git://git.eclipse.org/gitroot/cdt/org.eclipse.cdt` and build that source code to make the CDT plugin.

(3) Open the fresh Eclipse.exe software and add the freshly built CDT plugin - somehow..

Thank you once again for your help. :-)

Comment: No idea tbh, i've never worked on the eclipse source. This is just my best guess

Comment: Thank you for your answers :-)

Answer (score 2):

If you want to build a specific package (for example the **IDE for C/C++ Developers** package), clone `https://git.eclipse.org/r/epp/org.eclipse.epp.packages` and then look at the `README.md` file - it has instructions for building locally.

Technically speaking, that's not building the "barebones" platform and then adding in features and plug-ins on your own, but I think you'll find this a much easier first step to get towards your goal (whatever that is).

Comment: My eventual goal is making the icons bigger. I've posted a link at the 3rd question: "Building Eclipse IDE from scratch - making bigger icons sometimes successful". Maybe you can give me some advices on that topic? Thank you so much for your help. :-)