# Building Eclipse IDE from scratch - making bigger icons sometimes successful

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, icons

Even the newest Eclipse Neon edition has still somewhat small icons on a 4k display. That is why I'm trying to make them bigger. I resorted to building the Eclipse IDE from scratch for that purpose.
[image]

Please read this StackOverflow question to see how I did that:

[Building Eclipse IDE from scratch - how to choose CDT over JDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929070/building-eclipse-ide-from-scratch-how-to-choose-cdt-over-jdt/37929362?noredirect=1#comment63309900_37929362)

I wrote a Windows batch file that runs through all the folders and changes the size of every icon it can find. In my batch file, I presume that every `.png` , `.gif`, `.bmp`, `.jpg` and `.ico` file with dimensions below 48x48 pixels is an icon. And I double the size.

I run that batch file just before starting the build.

I get mixed results. The figure below shows that some icons do get much bigger - but others don't. Take for example the `debug icon`. It looks like its dimensions are still the old 16x16 pixels. Maybe my batch file was not complete, and it somehow skipped that one. So I check the eclipse sourcecode folders and find the `debug icon`. It is 32x32 pixels! So my batch file was correct. Why doesn't the eclipse build use it correctly?

[image]

Any help would be much appreciated. If I succeed to make all icons larger, I promise to share the solution with everyone (and mention your contribution) :-)

I believe the small Eclipse icons are a real pain for all people with high dpi displays or those people who are not blessed with eagle eyes. **Developing code should not be a privilege for those with sharp eyesight - it should be accessible to all.**

---

PS: I've got some other questions related to the Eclipse "Build from scratch" topic. If you're interested:

- [Building Eclipse IDE from scratch - how to choose CDT over JDT?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929070/building-eclipse-ide-from-scratch-how-to-choose-cdt-over-jdt)
- [Building Eclipse IDE from scratch - how to specify the target OS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37885323/building-eclipse-ide-from-scratch-how-to-specify-the-target-os)
- [Building Eclipse IDE from scratch - making bigger icons sometimes successful](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37929996/building-eclipse-ide-from-scratch-making-bigger-icons-sometimes-successful)

Let us all unite to build the Eclipse IDE ourselves - and tweak it to our needs ;-)

[image]

Comment: The layout would affect (among other things) the maximum size of images, so just doubling all the images can't be enough.

Comment: But why does it work perfect for some icons - and not at all for others?

Comment: Because the layout is different in different places. You'll notice that the big icons don't have a dropdown option in the button.

Comment: Oh, that's interesting. Do you know how to make my approach work for the other icons too? Probably this means diving into the code. Sadly I don't have a clue where to start. Maybe you can give me some hints ;-)

Comment: I'm no Eclipse expert, but I'd suspect that it involves a non-trivial amount of work.

Comment: I hope that an eclipse contributer accidentally sees this post - and help us all. That would be wonderful.

Comment: There is some effort already underway to improve rendering on High-DPI displays. See, for example, https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=382972 (look at the last 1/3 of comments). Also https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=462952. Those are available in the latest 4.6 (Neon) RC builds. Neon will be released later this week, if you want to wait.

Comment: The approach you're taking definitely sounds very hacky; the Eclipse platform and widget toolkit should handle the scaling, which is what those bugs are about. I suspect you'll never get a really satisfactory result by just brute-force increasing image sizes - good rendering is far more complex than that.

Comment: That's great! But I noticed that Eclipse Neon only improves the icons from 16 to 32 pixels. I had hoped for even larger ones (64x64 pixels for example).

Comment: Are you one of the eclipse developers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

From the screen shot I believe you are running with 100% scaling factor on 4k screen. You can specify the scaling factor to 200%. The scaling in eclipse is controlled by this. In Neon only multiples of 100% scaling factors supported. With this you'll see all drawing code and images scaled. If you need even bigger put the scaling factor to 300%, 400% etc. We have only 2x images available. You may see the images blurry on higher scaling factors. But the graphics like lines rectangles does work properly.

in Windows 7 go to Control Panel\Appearance and Personalization\Display and use custom dpi settings to 200%(if it is not available, on 4k 200% should be available by default).

in Windows 10 go to customize display and set the slider "Change size of text, apps and other items" to 200%.

This will make the eclipse scaleup. You need to restart eclipse after changing these settings. I suggest logout and login again to get this change to full effect.

If this did not help please raise a bug against platform SWT with [HiDpi] tag.

P.S. I spent considerable amount of time to make these icons scaled on high dpi monitors. You should not be required to scale up the icons. Swt does the work for you. What is required is setting the correct scale factor in the display settings

Comment: Thank you so much. Are you one of the Eclipse developers?

Comment: Thank you so much for this excellent work you did. I really appreciate your contribution to the Eclipse project. Bigger icons is something that many people have been waiting for. I decided to donate you 50 points from my own StackOverflow account (through a bounty). Apparently I need to wait 23 hours to actually transfer the bounty to you. So tomorrow you'll get it :-)

Comment: Thank you for the offer. If you find any difficulty in using this, please don't hesitate to contact me

Comment: You're welcome Mr. Sravan. You really deserve this! Your work makes the life of many people working with Eclipse much more convenient :-)

Answer (score 4):

In Eclipse Neon, you can add following VM argument in the ***eclipse.ini*** or on the command line after `-vmargs` to double the size of all icons (see [Tweaking SWT's auto-scaling](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipse/news/4.6/platform.php#swt-autoscale-tweaks)):

```
-Dswt.autoScale=200
```

This will use the `*@2x.png` icons if available: 
[image: Eclipse IDE without and an Eclipse IDE with "-Dswt.autoScale=200"]

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/davidglevy/eclipse-icon-enlarger#eclipse-icon-enlarger
: Icon enlarger software (zip folder).

[image]
  [image][image]

[image]

Comment: How should one use this project? The Readme file does not give any details.

Comment: So I clone or download the git repository.. and then what happens? I have no clue on the next steps, since the Readme.md file doesn't specify anything.

Comment: It does... Just re-open it